# Android Nine-patch equivalent for other platforms

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have just learned about Android nine-patches idea, and it is a pretty good idea. My question is if it is an Android pattern or there is implementations like that for other platforms, probably differently named.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS you can also strech images in code with StretchableImages. You specify the left, right caps and the "rest" is stretched. I think is basicaly the same idea, this is something like a tutorial on it: http://blog.chomperstomp.com/creating-dynamically-re-sizable-buttons-for-iphone-apps/

Answer (score 2):

There is another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134825/is-there-a-nine-patch-loader-for-iphone) that mentions a library released under Apache license for iPhone. I haven't used it but is worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks! This is really similar to Android NinePatch!