# stretch a Image like android nine-patch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nine-patch

`UIImage` Method :

`- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight`.

Here the stretchable area is forced to be a single pixel high/wide.

I can not set the stretchable area, so I want to know: is there a UIImage category to do that?

After I googled, I found a lib.

**Question:** [Is there a nine-patch loader for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134825/is-there-a-nine-patch-loader-for-iphone)

**Announcement:** http://blog.tortuga22.com/2010/05/31/announcing-tortuga-22-ninepatch/

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc6my.png]

This is a source pic, and I want to stretch the inside gray rect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using the nine-patch-loader-for-iphone

Comment: there may have a better solution,like a uiimage category,sth like this:
- (UIImage *)imageWithStretchableRect:(CGRect)rect destRect:(CGRect)destRect

Comment: i use this lib,and the affect is not what i want . i want to repeat some part of the image .

Answer (score 20):

One way to achieve this is using the below approach,

```
UIImage * backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];

backgroundImg = [backgroundImg resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,2, 2, 2)];

[imgView setImage: backgroundImg];
```

UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,2, 2, 2) is the amount of pixels you want unstretchable.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve nine patch with [Tortuga22 software](http://blog.tortuga22.com/2010/05/31/announcing-tortuga-22-ninepatch/)

You can find source from this GitHub [here](https://github.com/tortuga22/Tortuga22-NinePatch)

Use it like this

```
[btnSubmit setImage: [TUNinePatchCache imageOfSize:[btnSubmit bounds].size 
                                forNinePatchNamed:@"imgNormalBackground"]
                       forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS5, you can use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to load so much code for the simple 9 patch images we had. So anyway, here's a simple solution to the problem for those interested. It's somewhat hard coded to our 3 pixel stretch regions but you could easily adjust those to your needs or find those in the image with some basic code and use that instead of my hard-coded inset parameters.

```
+ (UIImage *) makeNinePatchImage:(UIImage *)image;
{
    //Clear the black 9patch regions
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, 1));
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, image.size.height));

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIEdgeInsets insets;

    //hard coded for now, could easily read the black regions if necessary
    insets.left = insets.right = image.size.width / 2 - 1;
    insets.top = insets.bottom = image.size.height / 2 - 1;

    UIImage *nineImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets     
                          resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

    return nineImage;

}
```

Then to use it in say, a button's background, just call it like this:

```
[self.dummyButton setBackgroundImage:[EVUtility makeNinePatchImage:learnMoreImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you want the rectangle to grow in length and height.
While there may be a more efficient solutions, what I could suggest is to break the boundary into a basic unit. Add this image repeatedly one next to the other to form the border rectangle of desired length and height. Then paint the inner rect with gray color.

Comment: yes,exactly.i just want to repeat only part of image
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901059/how-to-repeat-only-part-of-an-image   thanks for you reply. your answer did help me