# how to repeat only part of an image?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

how to repeat only part of an image,

there are two images.

*i.stack.imgur.com/KC0Pm.png*

the source pic is something like the above
and i want to change it to:

*i.stack.imgur.com/t8CwQ.png*

this means i just want to repeat only part of the image? not stretch the source pic,
is it possible to do that?

thanks
**Update:**

CODE HERE : http://www.box.net/shared/cmtz0e48a5urtajxu4yn
still have problem!!

**Update:**
i crop my image file and just repeat the part,but i still have some problem.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(NSString *)iconName covertToSize:(CGSize)size {
CGRect topLeft,topRight,bottomLeft,bottomRight,top,bottom,left,right;
if ([iconName isEqualToString:@"border_baikuang"]) {
    topLeft = CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18);
    topRight = CGRectMake(108-18, 0, 18, 18);
    bottomLeft = CGRectMake(0, 104-18, 18, 18);
    bottomRight = CGRectMake(108-18, 104-18, 18, 18);
    top = CGRectMake(18, 0, 1, 18);
    bottom = CGRectMake(18, 104-18, 1, 18);
    left = CGRectMake(0, 18, 18, 1);
    right = CGRectMake(108-18, 18, 18, 1);
} else if ([iconName isEqualToString:@"border_fuguxiangkuang"]) {
    topLeft = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 28);
    topRight = CGRectMake(108-28, 0, 28, 28);
    bottomLeft = CGRectMake(0, 104-28, 28, 28);
    bottomRight = CGRectMake(108-28, 104-28, 28, 28);
    top = CGRectMake(28, 0, 28, 24);
    bottom = CGRectMake(28, 104-28, 28, 24);
    left = CGRectMake(0, 28, 24, 28);
    right = CGRectMake(108-24, 28, 24, 28);
}
float width = size.width;
float height = size.height;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
//
UIImage *topLeftPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:topLeft];
[topLeftPattern drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, topLeftPattern.size.width, topLeftPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *topRightPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:topRight];
[topRightPattern drawInRect:CGRectMake(width-topRightPattern.size.width, 0, topRightPattern.size.width, topRightPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *bottomLeftPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:bottomLeft];
[bottomLeftPattern drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, height-bottomLeftPattern.size.height, bottomLeftPattern.size.width, bottomLeftPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *bottomRightPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:bottomRight];
[bottomRightPattern drawInRect:CGRectMake(width-bottomRightPattern.size.width, height-bottomRightPattern.size.height, bottomRightPattern.size.width, bottomRightPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *topPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:top];
[topPattern drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(topLeftPattern.size.width, 0, width-topRightPattern.size.width-topLeftPattern.size.width, topPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *bottomPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:bottom];
[bottomPattern drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(bottomLeftPattern.size.width, height-bottomLeftPattern.size.height, width-bottomRightPattern.size.width-bottomLeftPattern.size.width, bottomPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *leftPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:left];
[leftPattern drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(0, topLeftPattern.size.height, leftPattern.size.width, height-bottomLeftPattern.size.height-topLeftPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *rightPattern = [self fetchImgWithSrc:iconName rect:right];
[rightPattern drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(width-topRightPattern.size.width, topRightPattern.size.height, rightPattern.size.width, height-bottomRightPattern.size.height - topRightPattern.size.height)];

UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return destImage;
```

}

```
- (UIImage*)fetchImgWithSrc:(NSString *)iconName rect:(CGRect)clipRect {

NSString *completeName = [iconName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
UIImage *src = [UIImage imageFromFileName:completeName];
NSLog(@"src=%@",NSStringFromCGSize(src.size));
UIImage *tmpPattern = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(src.CGImage, clipRect)];
NSLog(@"dest=%@",NSStringFromCGSize(tmpPattern.size));
return tmpPattern;
```

}

the result is like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO0O5.png

is there something wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

There's `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` (up to 4.3) or `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` in iOS 5

Answer (score 1):

With UIImage you can only repeat a 1 pixel wide part of the image. The best thing you can do is to crop your image file and just repeat the part you want to repeat. You can do it with Core Graphics too, but it's much more complicated than modifying your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDrawThreePartImage` (OSX only) for a hint at one potential solution.

It is declared like so:

```
void NSDrawThreePartImage(NSRect frame,
   NSImage *startCap,
   NSImage *centerFill,
   NSImage *endCap,
   BOOL vertical,
   NSCompositingOperation op,
   CGFloat alphaFraction,
   BOOL flipped
);
```

So you will need three images to simulate this.

You can actually do this with one image and some fancy CoreGraphics manipulations if you also know the offsets.

The first thing that comes to mind when simulating this would be to use a `CGBitmapContext`, then just draw the images where you want them to the bitmap using the context, then take the result as a bitmap or `CGImage` (you'll probably want to save the result, because it can be expensive to compute).