# UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets cap data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, resizable

I've used stretchable images before and whenever I use them I have to manually type in the cap insets and if I get them wrong the image looks wrong.

Is there any way of "implanting" the cap data into some file that can then be read along with the image.

i.e.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage loadResizableImageWithFile:"someFile"];
```

That way the designers can input the cap sizes of the image instead of me having to type them in manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` Method to achive this. Provided sample code.

```
CGSize imgSize = stretchableImage.size;
if ([stretchableImage respondsToSelector:@selector(stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:)]) {
    stretchableImage = [stretchableImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(imgSize.width/2.0) - 1 topCapHeight:(imgSize.height/2.0) - 1];
} else {
    stretchableImage = [stretchableImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake((imgSize.height/2.0) - 1, (imgSize.width/2.0) - 1, (imgSize.height/2.0) - 1, (imgSize.width/2.0) - 1)];
}
```

Comment: That method is deprecated since iOS 5. I know how to use it. In your example you have manually typed out what the cap sizes are. That's what I'm trying to avoid. So the designer can provide a plist file or something.

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't natively offer a mechanism to embed the stretchable portions in the image itself.

I know android does this by adding a 1 pixel border around the image and uses black pixels in that border to indicate the stretchable part.

A quick search here on stack overflow leads to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2959760/474896) that links to an iOS alternative: [Tortuga22-NinePatch](https://github.com/tortuga22/Tortuga22-NinePatch) (Apache licensed)